# Jordan Canonical Form transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have this matrix $M$

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1\\
        2 & 1 & -1\\
        0 & -1 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}$

And I was asked to put it into Jordan Canonical Form.

I did this, and obtained

if $M$ = $SQS^{-1}$

Then $S = \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 0 & -1\\
        4 & -1 & -1\\
        2 & 1 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}$

And $Q = \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 2 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 2
        \end{bmatrix}$  is the matrix of jordan blocks

I am now asked to "find the appropriate transition matrix to the basis in which the the original matrix assumes its Jordan form."  Needless to say I have no idea what it is asking and any clarification would be largely appreciated.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered the question.  $Q$ is the "Jordan canonical form", and $S^{-1}$ is "the appropriate transition matrix to the basis in which the original matrix assumes its normal form."